# Error ngTable AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ngtable, referenceerror

I'm using ngTable (AngularJS) to display a list of elements, but I get an error when compiling:

> ************ I am OK ******************

*articles.client.controller.js:12 ReferenceError: articles is not defined at new  (...../modules/articles/controllers articles.client.controller.js:27:16)*

This is my code: *myApp/public/modules/articles/controllers articles.client.controller.js*

```
'use strict';

angular.module('articles').controller('ArticlesController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 
    'Authentication', 'Articles', 
    function($scope, $filter, ngTableParams, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Articles){

        $scope.authentication = Authentication;
        $scope.find = function() {
            $scope.articles = Articles.query();
        };

        console.log('************ I am OK ******************');

        /* jshint ignore:start */

        $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({

            page: 1,            // show first page
            count: 10,          // count per page
            filter: {
                title: ''       // initial filter
            },
            sorting: {
                title: 'asc'     // initial sorting
            }
        }, {
            total: articles.length, // length of data
            getData: function($defer, params) {
                // use build-in angular filter
                var filteredData = params.filter() ?
                    $filter('filter')(articles, params.filter()) :
                    articles;
                var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                    $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) :
                    articles;

                params.total(orderedData.length); // set total for recalc pagination
                $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
            }
        });
        /* jshint ignore:end */

        $scope.create = function() {
            var article = new Articles({
                title: this.title,
                content: this.content
            });
            article.$save(function(response) {
                $location.path('articles/' + response._id);
            }, function(errorResponse) {
                $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
            });

            this.title = '';
            this.content = '';
        };

        $scope.remove = function(article) {
            if (article) {
                article.$remove();

                for (var i in $scope.articles) {
                    if ($scope.articles[i] === article) {
                        $scope.articles.splice(i, 1);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $scope.article.$remove(function() {
                    $location.path('articles');
                });
            }
        };

        $scope.update = function() {
            var article = $scope.article;

            article.$update(function() {
                $location.path('articles/' + article._id);
            }, function(errorResponse) {
                $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
            });
        };
    }
]);
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use #ngTasty http://zizzamia.com/ng-tasty/ it's way easier!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is where the interpreter told you it was:

```
total: articles.length, // length of data
```

should be

```
total: $scope.articles.length, // length of data
```

Of course, $scope.articles doesn't exist when you create your ngTable params, so you'll have to find some way to set that value at the right time (maybe in your getData method)

Answer (score 0):

Even your `$scope.articles` will not be available until you call the `$scope.find` method, so firstly you need to instantiate `$scope.articles variable` or just write call `$scope.find()` even before you declare `$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({ })`. This will work.

But for better code, wrap `$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({ })` in a method and use `ng-init` to call `$scope.find()`